# Where did the hot network questions go? Are they gone forever, or is this just A/B testing?

Tags: support, hot-questions

My beautiful hot network questions are all gone :(

I see a Recent Tags section

[image]

And a Recent Badges section

[image]

neither of which I remember seeing before (and as a side-note, I don't see the value of these additional sections; can't see myself ever using them).

Is this just A/B Testing, or is this the end of HNQ? If this is the end, is there a blog post explaining this? Because I am distraught.

---

Edit: Right after posting this, I see them again! So was this just a glitch then?

Comment: This *used* to be the homepage layout back during the era of the old, pre-2014 top bar, back when "hot questions" was accessed there instead.

Comment: I can confirm that they disappeared for a few minutes for me too.

Comment: "I don't always test my code, but when i do..."

Comment: Oooh, how do I sign up for the B group?

Comment: Oh which site did this error occur to you?

Comment: @MEEisJohannGambolputty... I saw this on multiple sites. The two I remember for sure are SO and MSE.

Comment: @pushkin okay because I was wondering whether this was on MathOverflow, because it would be by design then, but thanks.