# "Recent Badges" list is displayed without margins on "Home" page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, badges, homepage

When the "Hide Hot Network Questions" preference is enabled (i.e. HNQ sidebar is hidden), we see "Recent Tags" and "Recent Badges" in the homepage instead of the HNQ.

However, the "Recent Badges" list is displayed with no margins.

ex.) https://meta.stackexchange.com/

[image]

I think that the appropriate margins were set in the past.

cf.) [Where did the hot network questions go? Are they gone forever, or is this just A/B testing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324261)

[image]

Comment: Key bit: you have to hide the hot questions in https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current to see this in the first place

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating Specifically, it refers to the "home" page, such as https://meta.stackexchange.com/ (Scroll down the page and you should see it in the bottom right corner.)

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating yes I see it too, without any userscripts and on sites that don't use black theme.

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating A/B tests is irrelevant. You just open https://meta.stackexchange.com/ (It is not displayed when you are logged out.)

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating I hadn't thought of A/B, I'm seeing this in Firefox+Windows (don't really have the patience to try other combinations right now...) Just opening [badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges) it's immediately visible.

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating did you hide HNQ in preferences?

Comment: @muru no, I [do see the HNQ sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWoF6.png).

Comment: OK, finally the missing puzzle was found, @cubick you should really have mentioned it before, not everyone choose to hide the HNQ sidebar. Anyway, back to the bug: I see the list fine, with 1px margin. What browser you have?

Comment: Related to the comments: [Why is there now a long list of tags and badges recently achieved by named individuals down the right hand side of the SO homepage?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405646/4642212)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has been fixed and the fix is live in production. Thanks for the report!