# Recent Badges lack spacing

Tags: bug, design, badges, sidebar

Today I noticed that the list of recent badges in the sidebar (visible when HNQ is de-activated, or on the [/badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/badges) pages) lack spacing between the badges themselves.

The spacing between the users who obtained the badges looks appropriate, but the spacing between the different badges is missing. Desired behaviour would resemble that of the tags that are listed in the upper half of below screenshot.

[image: Example taken from MathOverflow.net]

Comment: Already reported: [“Recent Badges” list is displayed without margins on “Home” page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360533/289905).

Comment: Thanks for the link @SebastianSimon. Yay for SE search once again -_-

Comment: Pro-tip: just read all of Meta, all the time, forever, and never delete your browser history. 